# I can't pass some value from html checkbox array to my php page?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I created the product management system that use HTML+PHP+SQL+JS.But it's have a problem 
some value can't pass to php page to SQL query.I can't find any bug in my code because some data can do that normally. 
my system use the checkbox array to choose each product that i want to do with them

```
echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"ProductKey[]\" value=\"".$Key."\"/></td>";
```

and pass them to any target by javascript like this

```
<input type='button' id='edit' onclick="OnButtonEdit();" class = "btn btn-success" value='add'></br></br>
<input type='button' id='delete' onclick="OnButtonDelete();" class = "btn btn-warning" value='subtract'></br></br>
<input type='button' id='delete' onclick="OnButtonRemove();" class = "btn btn-danger" value='remove'></br></br>
<input type='button' id='delete' onclick="OnButtonProductbackquery();" class = "btn btn-info" value='pass back to homestock'></br>
```

in php page that receive value to sql query

```
foreach ($_POST['ProductKey'] as $Key){
....
}
```

The Example data that can pass

```
ProductKey | Size | Colour | Price | Cost | Quantity | Customer | ProductKey | AccountKey
DK9973 | 42 | Black | 550 | 280 |1 | ram35 | 57872 | 128
```

Example data that can't pass

```
ProductKey | Size | Colour | Price | Cost | Quantity | Customer | ProductKey | AccountKey
A056 | 40 | Brown | 350 | 220 |1 | ram35 | 58784 | 133
```

some javascript button function

```
 function OnButtonDelete() {
    document.myform.action = "delete.php";
    document.myform.target = "_self";
    document.myform.submit();
    return true;  
  }
```

Thanks for all answer ,If you want more code please tell me :)

Comment: but then the values get to php, but not to mysql? have you tried to print_r($_POST['ProductKey']) and see if the values are actually passing _

Comment: I'd like to see one of the OnButton javascript functions to make sure the variables are being posted.

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes are not submitted. ID's can't have the same value (delete) - but this is maybe a typo?

Comment: @aleation it did't show any thing.

Comment: It may be the limit of checkbox in form ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I solved it!! 
it should be the html checkbox maximum in one form.
I tried to make the search input that query from ProductID
it make the number of checkbox in one form decrease 
but,now it work for all product.

I don't sure about this solution,but it's work.

Answer (score 1):

If your checkbox is not checked, it will not exist in the php page who receive the post data.

Just test :

```
if(isset($_POST['ProductKey'])){
  //Checkbox checked
} else {
  //Checkbox not checked
}
```

Comment: it's show that check box is not check.I test with print_r($_POST); it didn't pass checkbox value.